# DOM undefined error

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined

I'm suddenly getting error like this on firebug. What do I look for? What does it mean?

```
nodes.item(i).getElementsByTagName("div")[0] is undefined
```

Comment: You should post your code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a collection of elements in `nodes`.  Apparently, you're looping through them with `i`.  Then, **IN EACH ONE**, you're looking for any `DIV`s.  If you find any `DIV`s, you're examining the first ("zero-th") one.

So, apparently, one of your `item[i]`s is missing the `DIV` that your brain thinks is there, but the computer says is not actually there.

And, since it can't find the "zero-th" one, that means there are NO DIVS AT ALL in that child.

So, look for that.  :)

Comment: Solved! Thanks for translating it in a language I can understand Weew! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is no element under `nodes.item(i)` with the `tagName` **div**.

Comment: Thanks Man! Figured this out by reading the code from bottom to top. Some element was missing at the top that cause the code not to find <div> tag ^^